# Why is SonarQube not respecting my exclusions?

Tags: eclipse, maven, sonarqube

I have a Java project that I am developing in Eclipse and building with Maven. Almost all of my source bundles (in /src) have a corresponding test bundle (in /tests). I would like my SonarQube Maven build to only analyze the source bundles and ignore the test bundles. From my `pom.xml` in a bundle in the file system at the same level as /src and /tests, I have something similar to the following:

```
...
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    ...
    <properties>
        <sonar.skippedModules>**/tests/**</sonar.skippedModules>
    </properties>
</profile>
...
<modules>
    <module>../src/com.company.bundleA</module>
    <module>../tests/com.company.bundleA.test</module>
    ...
</modules>
```

When I run the build, the source code in the test bundles is included in the SonarQube analysis. Alternatively, I have tried using the `sonar.test.exclusions` and `sonar.exclusions` properties in place of `sonar.skippedModules`. With the exclusions properties, the console output shows that the exclusions are read but never matches any files to the expressions I've tried to use. I have also tried to set these properties in the in the Settings part of the SonarQube web server UI and have produced the same result of including the test files. The only way I have been able to successfully exclude the test bundles from analysis is to remove them from the list of modules or include them after a `-Dsonar.skippedModules` flag in the Goals field of my run configuration. However, this is not a maintainable solution for a project that includes over 80 total bundles and 140,000 lines of code. Is there something wrong with the organization of the `pom.xml` file? This is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

First, `sonar.skippedModules` does not accept wildcard patterns - which might be the first reason why this does not work.

Second, this property has been deprecated in SonarQube 4.3, see [SONAR-5109](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5109). This was replaced by "sonar.skip" in recent versions (see [MSONAR-46](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR-46))

Comment: I've replaced `sonar.skippedModules` with `sonar.skip` and eliminated my use of wildcards. Enclosed in `sonar.skip`, I've tried both `com.company.bundleA.test,com.company.bundleB.test` and `../tests/com.company.bundleA.test,../tests/com.company.bundleB.test` with no success. Is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: IIRC, sonar.skip must be set in the POM of each module that you want to skip.